# node-gyp creates on error on Docker build

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, node-gyp

I am trying to build a node docker image from my m1 macbook.  This is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:16-alpine
COPY . /api
WORKDIR /api
RUN npm ci --omit=dev && \
    npm run build && \
    npm prune --production

ENTRYPOINT sh -c "cd /api/build/dist && npm run start"

EXPOSE 8080
```

This works for my colleages on non-m1 macbooks by running `docker build .`.   On mine however I get this error

```
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for sqlite3@5.1.6 and node@16.20.2 (node-v93 ABI, musl) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 407 AuthorizedOnly on https://artifactory.company.com/node_sqlite3/v5.1.6/napi-v6-linux-musl-arm64.tar.gz 
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="/path/to/pythonexecutable"
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "/path/to/pythonexecutable"
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! find Python 
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:330:47)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:159:21)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:202:16)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/find-python.js:294:16)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (node:child_process:410:5)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (node:child_process:422:5)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:485:16)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 6.4.16-linuxkit
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/api/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-musl-arm64/node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=/api/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-musl-arm64" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=6" "--node_napi_label=napi-v6"
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /api/node_modules/sqlite3
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.2
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
15.26 npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/api/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-musl-arm64/node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=/api/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-musl-arm64 --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=6 --node_napi_label=napi-v6' (1)
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/api/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1100:16)
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 6.4.16-linuxkit
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/api/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /api/node_modules/sqlite3
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.2
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.10
15.26 npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

I've tried absolutely everything with no luck!